# Can't stop wordpress site from redirecting to the old installation folder

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically the whole site was like this when I took it: sitename.com/wp <- it was the official address  of the whole site.
I tried moving all files from public_html/wp to just public_html. It didn't work of course. I gave up and deleted database and made my own and installed the wordpress once again. Now I am able to log in and even though I have access for example to this url: https://sitename.com/wp-admin/options-general.php I still am redirected to sitename.com/wp when I try to go to sitename.com. Is there an option to make it work normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few places to see for this issue
First of all disable all the cache plugins if any and browser's cache
Secondly, check in wordpress settings the URLs that you have there (settings - general)
Make sure you have the default htaccess file, before that take a backup of everything

Maybe a site url would be helpful;